# SQL logic for the Vlookup function in excel/ How to do a Vlookup in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns OLD_VALUE and NEW_VALUE and 5 rows. 1st row has values (A,B). Other row values can be (B,C),(C,D),(E,D),(D,F). I want to update all the old values with the new value (how a vlookup in excel would work) The Final Result Required: The newest value in the above example would be D,F. i.e. D points to F. E and C point to D. B points to C and A points to B. D pointing to F is the last and newest and there are no more successions after D,F. So (OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE)->(A,F), (B,F), (C,F), (D,F), (E,F). I want 5 rows with the NEW_VALUE as 'F'. The level of successions can be ranging from 1 to x.

Comment: how do you know which row is 'first', which is 'last'? Do you have a column that signifies the order?

Comment: no, unfortunately there is no column that signifies the order.

Comment: So if you were doing this in Excel, you'd use 5 vlookups? The question isn't very clear ...

Comment: You are right. I did a vlookup 5 times in excel. But I am trying to automate this in SQL. But, the level of successions is not always 5 times with other set of OLD and NEW Values.

Comment: For example, there are 2 university courses-1) 'Theory of Computation' and 2) 'Analysis of Algorithm' that have course codes TOC and AOA repectively. The university decides to  merge these 2 courses into 1 course AOA from this year. Like this there can be more than 3 course that have a new course name. But the problem is they do not have the direct new value in the sql table. A points to B, B points to C and C points to D. So, all the 3 course A,B and C should ultimately be updated to D

Comment: From your comments you seem to have a solution. Please mark one of the answers as 'accepted' by way of a thank you to them, and to help others find useful responses.

Comment: Yep just learnt how to 'accept' an answer! and you can accept only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a recursive CTE like the following is what you're looking for (where the parent is the row whose second value does not exist as a first value elsewhere). If there's no parent(s) to anchor to, this would fail (e.g. if you had A->B, B->C, C->A, you'd get no result), but it should work for your case:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (val1 CHAR(1), val2 CHAR(2));
INSERT @T VALUES ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('E', 'D'), ('D', 'F');

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT val1, val2
    FROM @T AS T
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @T WHERE val1 = T.val2)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.val1, CTE.val2
    FROM @T AS T
    JOIN CTE
        ON CTE.val1 = T.val2
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the table I have used for the script:

```
declare @t as table(old_value char(1), new_value char(1));
insert into @t values('A','B')
insert into @t values('B','C')
insert into @t values('C','D')
insert into @t values('E','D')
insert into @t values('D','F')
```

This needs to be done with a recursive CTE. First, you will need to define an anchor for the CTE. The anchor in this case should be the record with the latest value. This is how I define the anchor:

```
select old_value, new_value, 1 as level 
from @t 
where new_value NOT IN (select old_value from @t)
```

And here is the recursive CTE I used to locate the latest value for each row:

```
;with a as(
select old_value, new_value, 1 as level 
from @t 
where new_value NOT IN (select old_value from @t)
union all 
select b.old_value, a.new_value, a.level + 1
from a INNER JOIN @t b ON a.old_value = b.new_value
)
select * from a
```

Results:

```
old_value new_value level
--------- --------- -----------
D         F         1
C         F         2
E         F         2
B         F         3
A         F         4

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Appreciate it! :)

Comment: I learned something from this, I'd been thinking it had to go from A to F, but you built it in the other direction. I'll have to remember that.